# Request and callback design

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

I am just trying to improve my coding and designing skills in C++ and for that 
I am trying to solve same age old problem of mapping a http request to method.

Could you guys please look at my program and point me to mistakes I am doing with design and coding style?

**resource.hpp**

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>


typedef std::function<void(void)> Handler;

enum class RequestMethod {
  GET,
  PUT,
  POST,
  DELETE
};

class Resource {

  public:
    Resource() {}  
    void SetMethodHandler(const RequestMethod method, const Handler& callback);
    Handler GetMethodHandler();

    void SetPath(const std::string& path);
    std::string& GetPath();

  private:
    Resource(const Resource& other) = delete;
    Resource& operator=(Resource& rhs) = delete;

    std::string m_path;
    RequestMethod m_method;
    Handler m_callback;
};
```

**resource.cpp**

```
#include "resource.hpp"

void Resource::SetPath(const std::string& path) {
  m_path = path;
}


std::string& Resource :: GetPath() {
  return m_path;
}

void Resource :: SetMethodHandler(RequestMethod method, const Handler& callback) {
  m_method = method;
  m_callback = callback;
}

Handler Resource :: GetMethodHandler() {
  return m_callback;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "resource.hpp"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void LoginMethodHandler() {
  std::cout << "Code here to handle a login request." << std::endl;
}

int main() {

  using ResourceSharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<Resource>;

  ResourceSharedPtr resource_ptr = std::make_shared<Resource>();
  resource_ptr->SetPath("/login");
  resource_ptr->SetMethodHandler(RequestMethod::GET, LoginMethodHandler);

  /* call to method handler */
  /* ideally in full blown application, logic will be search for path and   
     method and call approriate handler */
  resource_ptr->GetMethodHandler()();

  auto path_map = std::make_pair(resource_ptr->GetPath(),resource_ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea to create an abstraction class for request handling is a good one..

A few remarks and/or changes to consider:

- This code is flagged as `C++14` but there is only `C++11` specific code.
- I like the idea of using scoped enumerations (`enum class ...`) instead of the old-style enumerations. Scoped enumerations are more strictly typed.
- There are no include guards in `resource.hpp`. They can protect against (potential) double inclusions.
- Copy construction and copy assignment have been deleted, but by convention, deleted functions are declared `public`, not `private`..
  As for the (deleted) copy assignment, the argument should be a `const` reference.
- In `main.cpp`, it is good pratice to keep the application specific include file (`resource.hpp`) under the system include files.
- get and set methods are defined in `resource.cpp`, but these functions are so limited,
  why not include them directly in the header file, which would essentially eliminate `resource.cpp`.
- For a default, compiler generated, constructor, it is common practice to use:

  `Resource() = default;`

  However, since an uninitialized object is created and populated with values after that, why not set those during construction ? - the constructor then becomes:

  `Resource(const std::string &path, RequestMethod method, const Handler& callback)
      : m_path{path}, m_method{method}, m_callback{callback} { }`

  The object can still be modified by calling set functions later.
- `Resource::GetPath()` returns a reference to an `lvalue` which gives callers direct access to `Resource::m_path`, which is private.
  Many consider this a violation of data encapsulation. Consider changing the return type to a plain `std::string`.
- A `std::map` is not used yet, but the intention seems to be to store a `std::pair` in a `std::map` called `path_map`. You can call `std::make_pair` directly on the map inserter:

  `std::map< std::string, ResourceSharedPtr> path_map;
  ...
  path_map.insert(std::make_pair(resource_ptr->GetPath(),resource_ptr));`
- If you are planning to use only the `ResourceSharedPtr` in combination with the `std::map` pair, you could possibly eliminate `m_path` inside the `Resource` class and use the `std::map` key. Otherwise they are redundant.

With this, the updated source code becomes:

**resource.hpp**

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_H
#define RESOURCE_H

#include <functional>
#include <string>

typedef std::function<void(void)> Handler;

enum class RequestMethod {
  GET,
  PUT,
  POST,
  DELETE
};

class Resource {

  public:
    Resource(const std::string &path, RequestMethod method, const Handler& callback) :
        m_path{path}, m_method{method}, m_callback{callback} { }
    void SetMethodHandler(const RequestMethod method, const Handler& callback)
    {
      m_method = method;
      m_callback = callback;
    }

    Handler GetMethodHandler() { return m_callback; }

    void SetPath(const std::string& path) { m_path = path; }
    std::string GetPath() { return m_path; }

    Resource(const Resource& other) = delete;
    Resource& operator=(const Resource& rhs) = delete;


private:
    std::string m_path;
    RequestMethod m_method;
    Handler m_callback;
};

#endif // RESOURCE_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

#include "resource.hpp"

void LoginMethodHandler()
{
  std::cout << "Code here to handle a login request." << std::endl;
}

using ResourceSharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<Resource>;

std::map<std::string, ResourceSharedPtr> path_map;


int main() {

  ResourceSharedPtr resource_ptr = std::make_shared<Resource>("/login",
                                                              RequestMethod::GET,
                                                              LoginMethodHandler);

  /* call to method handler */
  /* ideally in full blown application, logic will be search for path and
     method and call approriate handler */
  resource_ptr->GetMethodHandler()();

  path_map.insert(std::make_pair(resource_ptr->GetPath(),resource_ptr));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments @LWimsey. I addressed all of them.  

However I have just 2 concerns with them.  

1.  The reason I use multimap is coz, same path can be mapped to different method. For eg (GET, POST) to same /user path.   
2.  I liked the idea of eliminating default constructor. However one thing I noticed new is the usage of { } (curly braces) during member intialization. Just wanted to know, what benefit it will have over ( ) (old common brackets) approach.  
thanks.

Comment: @Neeraj Thank you for your quick reply.. I didn't know you were going to use `multimap`, but you can simply replace `map` with `multimap`.
Note that the `insert` return type is a plain `iterator` instead of a `pair<interator,bool>`. Reason is that an insert cannot fail on account of the multiple key property, so you don't need the `bool`

Comment: Curly braces is a new (C++11) initialization syntax that provides several benefits compared to the old parentheses syntax. Most important is that it prevents type narrowing.
For example, `int i{3.14}` produces an error since a `double` does not fit in an `int`, but `int i(3.14)` is fine and it will truncate the value and store 3 in the variable.